# Hibernate JPA Spring Boot ignore JSON attributes for specific requests

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am running into an issue with JPA where I am getting alot of extra data I do not need along with alot of my requests.  I know I can get around this by returning DTO's in my requests, but then I am routing usefulness of JPA so I was wondering if there is better way to solve this.

For example, I have two classes. One called Product Item and One called Supplier.  A product item, can have a supplier as a `ManyToOne` Relationship.  When I do a get Request to get a product Item, I don't need the address for the supplier. I just need the name and ID.  However, When I do a get request on the supplier, I do need all the information related to the supplier.  Is there a way to specify this beyond just returning a DTO without that information?

**ProductItem.java**

```
@Entity 
public class ProductItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Organization org;
    @ManyToOne
    private Supplier supplier;
    private String barCode;
    private String description;
    private String name;
    private Integer stock;
    private Integer caseQty;
    private BigDecimal caseCost;
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Note> notes;
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdOn;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updatedOn;
```

**Supplier.java**

```
@Entity 
public class Supplier {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Note> notes;
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address;
    @ManyToOne
    private Organization org;
```

**Current Get http://localhost:8080/productitem/1**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "org": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test",
        "address": {
             "name": "Test"
            },
        "website": null,
        "phone": null
    },
    "supplier": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Sams Club",
        "notes": [],
        "address": {
         "name": "Test"
        },
        "org": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test",
            "address": {
             "name": "Test"
            },
            "website": null,
            "phone": null
        }
    },
    "barCode": "UPC134",
    "description": "This is description. This is description. This is description. This is description. ",
    "name": "Sunchips",
    "stock": 10,
    "caseQty": 34,
    "caseCost": 29.99,
    "notes": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Product Item Created",
            "description": "Note created by user X on 12/16/2019 11:00PM"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Product Item Updated",
            "description": "Product ITem updated stock by user X on 12/16/2019 11:00PM"
        }
    ],
    "createdOn": "2019-02-28T13:44:39",
    "updatedOn": "2019-02-28T13:44:39"
}
```

**Trying to Achieve Get http://localhost:8080/productitem/1**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "org": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test",
        "address": null,
        "website": null,
        "phone": null
    },
    "supplier": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Sams Club",
    },
    "barCode": "UPC134",
    "description": "This is description. This is description. This is description. This is description. ",
    "name": "Sunchips",
    "stock": 10,
    "caseQty": 34,
    "caseCost": 29.99,
    "notes": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Product Item Created",
            "description": "Note created by user X on 12/16/2019 11:00PM"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Product Item Updated",
            "description": "Product ITem updated stock by user X on 12/16/2019 11:00PM"
        }
    ],
    "createdOn": "2019-02-28T13:44:39",
    "updatedOn": "2019-02-28T13:44:39"
}
```

**Trying to Achieve/Current Get http://localhost:8080/supplier/1**

```
 {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Sams Club",
        "notes": [],
        "address": {
         "name": "Test"
        },
        "org": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test",
            "address": null,
            "website": null,
            "phone": null
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jackson Json Views to control serialization/deserialization for certain controller methods. Brief example:

View definitions:

```
public class Views {
    public static class BriefSupplier {
    }

    public static class FullSupplier extends BriefSupplier {
    }
}
```

Supplier:

```
@Entity 
public class Supplier {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    @JsonView(Views.BriefSupplier.class)
    private Long id;
    @JsonView(Views.BriefSupplier.class)
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonView(Views.FullSupplier.class)
    private List<Note> notes;
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonView(Views.FullSupplier.class)
    private Address address;
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonView(Views.FullSupplier.class)
    private Organization org;
}
```

Controllers:

```
@JsonView(Views.BriefSupplier.class)
@RequestMapping("/product/{productId}")
public Product getProduct(@PathVariable int productId) { ... }

@JsonView(Views.FullSupplier.class)
@RequestMapping("/supplier/{supplierId}")
public Supplier getSupplier(@PathVariable int supplierId) { ... }
```

Comment: If I add @JsonView(Views.BriefSupplier.class) to the controller, I get an empty result returned with no errors.  If I remove that piece from the controller, it works properly but I get the full data back.  Any idea what's going on?

Comment: You probably need to annotate the getters instead of the fields or add @JsonProperty to the fields.

Comment: Neither of those seems to do the trick either, I am getting an empty result back {} with no errors. If I get the data via the controller without @JsonView, I get data.

Answer (score 0):

JPA will use all properties of the class, unless you specifically mark them with `@Transient`:

```
@Transient
private String agencyName;
```

The `@Column` annotation is purely optional, and is there to let you override the auto-generated column name. Furthermore, the length attribute of `@Column` is only used when auto-generating table definitions, it has no effect on the runtime.

Make sure that you import `javax.persistence.transient` and not some other package.

Comment: I do want JPA to use all properties of the class when I request the Supplier directly, but NOT when the supplier data comes with the product item data. I updated my initial question with current and expected responses.